# Calculating time difference in milliseconds for two given times with "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:ms" format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have two times.

StartTime :"2014/10/28 11:50:28:318"

EndTime : "2014/10/28 11:50:35:249"

I need to calculate the difference between them in milliseconds. I used moment to calculate it.
My Code:

```
var msElapsedTime = moment(EndTime , "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:sss").diff(moment(StartTime , "DD/MM/YYYY     HH:mm:ss:sss"));
```

Answer: 7000

It shows as milliseconds but taking a round value.

Comment: @jroot Thanks...I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing token [for milliseconds is **`SSS`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/), not `ms` or `sss`. Your date tokens were also in the wrong order.

```
var StartTime = "2014/10/28 11:50:28:318",
    EndTime   = "2014/10/28 11:50:35:249";

var msElapsedTime = moment(EndTime, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss:SSS").diff(moment(StartTime , "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss:SSS"))

alert(msElapsedTime); // 6931
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pure JS:

```
var StartTime  = new Date("2014/10/28 11:50:28:318");
var EndTime = new Date("2014/10/28 11:50:35:249");

console.log(EndTime - StartTime); // 6931
```

[JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/xb2s1dzz/)

Answer (score 0):

Construct it like this

```
var msElapsedTime = moment('2014/10/28 11:50:28.318').diff(moment('2014/10/28 11:50:35.249'));
```